# Failing to render object data from Django API to Vuejs frontend

Tags: django, vue.js

I've worked with Django 3.x for almost two years now and have just started using Vue js for about a week using the documentation to try and learn the intended way. So far my api access points work as intended whenever I DON'T use the Vue frontend to create objects. So, down to the code. I've tried to send the report via a prop from the Home.vue to the Detail.vue but for some reason it doesn't seem to load more than the noc_ticket. Just in case, the main.js for the router was made in haste when I was learning, I doubt its the issue, but you never know.

Here is my monke code:

***Home.vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-4">Dashboard</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Dashboard</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
              <div class="card-body">Report Archive</div>
              <div
                class="
                  card-footer
                  d-flex
                  align-items-center
                  justify-content-between
                "
              >
                <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href=""
                  >View Details</a
                >
                <div class="small text-white">
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card bg-danger text-white mb-4">
              <div class="card-body">Initial Report</div>
              <div
                class="
                  card-footer
                  d-flex
                  align-items-center
                  justify-content-between
                "
              >
                <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href=""
                  >View Details</a
                >
                <div class="small text-white">
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card bg-warning text-white mb-4">
              <div class="card-body">Report Update</div>
              <div
                class="
                  card-footer
                  d-flex
                  align-items-center
                  justify-content-between
                "
              >
                <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href=""
                  >View Details</a
                >
                <div class="small text-white">
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="card bg-success text-white mb-4">
              <div class="card-body" href="">Finalize Report</div>
              <div
                class="
                  card-footer
                  d-flex
                  align-items-center
                  justify-content-between
                "
              >
                <a class="small text-white stretched-link" href=""
                  >View Details</a
                >
                <div class="small text-white">
                  <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <h1>Summary Table</h1>
          <div class="container container-fluid">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">TSRM Ticket</th>
                  <th scope="col">Type Of Outage</th>
                  <th scope="col">Amount of Affected Clients</th>
                  <th scope="col">Impacted Municipalities</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <!-- start making the for loop here -->
                <tr v-for="report in reports" :key="report.pk">
                  <td>
                    <router-link
                      :to="{
                        name: 'detail',
                        params: { noc_ticket: report.noc_ticket },
                      }"
                    >
                      {{ report.noc_ticket }}</router-link
                    >
                  </td>

                  <td v-for="outage in report.outage_type" :key="outage.id">
                    {{ outage.outage_type }}
                  </td>
                  <td
                    v-for="client_amount in report.clients"
                    :key="client_amount.id"
                  >
                    {{ client_amount.client_amount }}
                  </td>

                  <td
                    v-for="municipality in report.municipalities.split('+')"
                    :key="municipality"
                  >
                    {{ municipality }},
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- End it here. -->
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <h1>
            <!-- {#            Mini Charts go here.#} -->
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import { apiService } from "../common/api.service.js";
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      reports: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getReports() {
      let endpoint = `api/report-list`;
      apiService(endpoint).then((data) => {
        this.reports.push(...data);
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getReports();
    console.log(this.reports);
  },
};
</script>
```

***Detail.Vue***

```
<template>
  <div class="detail container">
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">Report Details</h1>
        <p class="lead">Highlighted Report Table</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1 >{{ noc_ticket }}</h1>
    <p >{{ report.notes }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import { apiService } from "../common/api.service.js";
export default {
  name: "Report",
  props: {
    noc_ticket: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    
  },
  data() {
    return {
      report: {},
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getReportData() {
      let endpoint = `/api/report-detail/${this.noc_ticket}/`;
      apiService(endpoint).then(data => {
        Object.assign(this.report, data);
        // this.report = data;
      });
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.getReportData();
  },
};
</script>
```

***router/index.js***

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Detail from "../views/Detail.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/report-detail/:noc_ticket/",
    name: "detail",
    component: Detail,
    props: true,
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: '/',
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

***Edit***
I had forgotten to put in my console output, I apologize.
***Console Output***

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
2L3K4J2LK34J2L3:1 Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('undefined'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
2L3K4J2LK34J2L3:1 Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('undefined'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.
api.service.js?5ce5:21 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: there must be error in your console, open inspect element the console tab. there must be error somewhere. and you can do console.log(data). to see if you receive data you intended

Comment: `Unexpected token <` looks like HTML. Maybe the server returns a 404 HTML page instead of JSON.

Comment: That part I don't particularly understand, I'm passing the api service withou issues to the list of the Home.vue.